# importing quoted csv data into sql server

Tags: sql-server, import

I have data in a CSV file that looks like:

```
"2745","00","8824","02/15/99","-850.00","-144.20","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","-994.20","0.00",""
```

I'm trying to import it into a table in SQL Server using SSMS's Import Wizard and I think I'm getting conversion errors.

For example, column 2 (third one) is setup as a numeric in the table, Col 3 is setup as a date, and the import wizard is complaining about losing data in the conversion.  I can understand it's trying to convert from string to numeric or string to date, but how do I tell it to convert the data?  Is that possible with the import wizard?

If not, what's the recommended way?  Let it import into it's own table then copy the data over to the destination table doing the conversion during the copy?

Comment: You can write a custom query and `CONVERT`/`CAST` the necessary columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the Flat File Source, you can select the data types of incoming columns by selecting `Advanced` and then specifying the type for each column.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't appear to help.  If I tell it column 2 (third) is a numeric, it errors saying that it can't convert because of potential loss of data. - could it be a problem that all the values are quoted? I can get the text values to come across (first 2 and last columns)

    Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed.    The data conversion for column "Column 2" returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Comment: Then you have either some non-numeric data or need a larger scale in that field.  I would bring it into a temp/staging table as a string (all fields as string actually) and then load it into the destination table with a TSQL INSERT statement that handles all necessary conversions.  You could also create a full-fledged SSIS package to handle the conversion, but unless it's an import you're going to be doing on a regular basis, using the temp table makes the most sense.  The Import Wizard creates a simple SSIS package, but without any conversion logic.

Comment: I ended up changing the input file to be pipe delimited and removing the quotes.  This allowed me to then set the values of the inputs in the wizard, and it's importing now.  Thanks much for the help!

Comment: Happy to (try to) help.  Glad you were able to get through it.